# Removing redirect chain created by Cloudfront CDN

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, cdn

I have recently started using Amazon Cloudfront CDN and am now seeing the following error messages when testing with Pingdom:

> Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
>
> https://cdn.landedhouses.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/rotatingtweets/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js
>   https://www.landedhouses.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/rotatingtweets/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js

(and lots of similar messages - see https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cr3FYh/www.landedhouses.co.uk)

The CDN is set up to use https://, as is Wordpress, so I am not sure how to fix the issue. I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to how to resolve this? Thank you!!

Comment: Problem resolved itself after 48 hours; possibly as the cache picked up files from the source server.

Answer (score 0):

Please setup the CloudFront as the AWS documentation. Create more Behaviours as following. This is the information AWS provided. All rights reserve to AWS.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/

[image]